# Hover style in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer

When i put a widget on a form in Qt Designer and change its style, i can omit `{}` parenthesis.

[image]

Is there a way to change a style for `hover` state without `{}`?

```
QWidget {
    background-color: rgba(32, 255, 8, 95);
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
QWidget:hover{
    background-color: rgba(32, 8, 255, 95);
}
```

This works, but i don't like duplication, and that all child widgets of the same class will inherit the style.

Comment: You can do QWidget#widgetName:hover. Then only the widget with specific name will have the style.

Comment: But then, i have to keep in mind to change the style if i change the widget name...

Comment: well you need something to identify the uniqueness of the widget. If you then change what makes it unique, you ofc need to change its implications. You end up with a Catch-22 logic. You can subclass QWidget to a CustomType and have selector based on type. However you can argue what happens if you change that class name :) You could also set the stylesheet from code and in code have the name retrieved at runtime with widget->objectName() [This will then not impact widget name changes in Qt Designer], but you then have style specification in code files.

Comment: I think QtCreator should have add re-factor to stylesheet. But currently I think refactor won't change the style sheet.